# Any difference from using StartCoroutine with just 0.5 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any difference if I just `yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f)`and just use normal function ?
Besides, there is a concept that I think I may have misunderstood it.Is those normal function like

```
void Update(){
command1 
command2 
}
```

After finishing compiling command1  , then start  compiling command 2 .or compile them at the same time since they 
belong to the same group .Please help to solve the problem .Sor for bad english.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I don't get it. `command1` and `command2` are running one after the other, but in the same frame. Perhaps some basic coding tutorial will help you: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/coding-in-unity-for-the-absolute-beginner#

Comment: well if you have a coroutine that has a 0.5s wait in it, one will wait 0.5s the other probably doesnt

Comment: so  the function is compiled in each frame , command1 compiles then command 2 compile . Since they are not compiled simultaneously,  the internal time may be 0.002s i guess . So if i use corotine solution : yield wait for 0.002 seconds .Two style of coding are the same?

Comment: It does not work that way. Coroutines (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) are not multithreaded.

Comment: I don't understand why Coroutines are not multithreaded is related to this problem .But  is there a difference that in Void Update() , even you set a timer or whatever , it finally still go to next flame, which  means the it is rhythmic ,the time is fixed; And if you use coroutine() , then when you set the time delay , it can happen over two or three flames , which is not rhythmic , the time is not fixed .Therefore  , it can perform somethings like animation play and wait for its end then start another command ,which can't be performed perfectly in void Update()

Comment: I think it's the main difference .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a difference.

A Coroutine that yields will return control to the main thread until that yield statement is resolved. (in this case your time delay of 0.5 seconds) Then it will resume the next line of code, again on the main thread.

A function will execute all of it's actions sequentially on the main thread and will not return control until all items are executed or you hit a return statement.